# AAPT cruncher image optimization removes resources from density buckets?

Tags: android, aapt

I decompiled my APK with apktool to check the resources of the app after build.

I was surprised that I couldn't find the drawable-mdpi folder in the decompiled source and a lot of the image resources was removed from drawable-xhdpi and drawable-hdpi.

If i turn off the cruncher in the aapt tool with

```
aaptOptions {
 cruncherEnabled = false
 }
```

then i get all the resource folders and resources added in Android Studio. (Screenshots below: On the left without aaptOptions in gradle, on the right with cruncher disabled) 
[image: Without aaptOptions] [image: Cruncher disabled])

I am using the 24 rc2 platform tools.

So my question is. Does it makes sens to create all the mdpi, xhdpi, hdpi resources and add them to the project if the AAPT removes them and keep the xxhdpi resources only?